# ActionScript 3: how do you compare if the object where you clicked on is that type of object

Tags: actionscript-3, object

I have a red box called mc1_mc and every time when you drag on it you get a new little blue box added to the stage. Yhe idea is that you can drag those blue boxes too. however I dont know how to detect them.

this is the code:

```
var newBlok:Boolean;
var blokIndex:int = 0;
var blokje:blok;
var huidigBlok:DisplayObject;
var prullenBak:DisplayObject = getChildByName("groen_mc");

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,pickUp);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropIt);

function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(event.currentTarget);
    trace(event.target);
    trace(event.target.name);

    if (event.target.name == "mc1_mc")
    {
        trace("hoi");

        blokje = new blok;  
        blokje.name = "blokje" + blokIndex;
        blokIndex++;

        addChild(blokje);
        blokje.startDrag(true);

    }

    if (event.target.type == blok)
    {
        trace("blok");
    }

    //blokjeVast = blokje;
}

function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
}
```

he wont ever come to the line: trace("blok"); 
even when the object i clicked on gives:

```
[object Stage]
[object blok]
blokje0
```

for the lines.

```
trace(event.currentTarget);
trace(event.target);
trace(event.target.name);
```

does anyone know how to do check if its a object of type "blok"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether an object is of a certain type, you can use the [is](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#is) operator.

So, you should change this:

```
if (event.target.type == blok)
{
    trace("blok");
}
```

To this:

```
if(event.target is blok) 
{
    trace("blok");
}
```

And if the target is of type blok, you should see the trace.

There's one caveat here. `ìs` tells you if an object is of a certain type. Since a class can extend other classes and implement interfaces, you should check for the most derived or specific one first (if you want to distinguish between, say, Sprite and MovieClip).

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

if(mc is MovieClip) {
    trace("is MovieClip");
} else if(mc is Sprite) {
    trace("is Sprite");
}

// even if mc is a MovieClip, your code will never get in the else block
if(mc is Sprite) {
    trace("is Sprite");
} else if(mc is MovieClip) {
    trace("is MovieClip");
}
```

Comment: thank you soooo much why does it always have to be so simple :S xD